# Why url is not displayed on the website how can i solve this issue is it because am using ip address instead of url example like "myipaddress"/mvc ??

Tags: php

***In php***

```
<?
    print_r($_GET['url']);
    ?>
```

**in .htaccess**

```
php_value error_reporting -1
php_flag display_errors on 
php_flag display_startup_errors on 

php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off


php_flag track_errors on 
php_flag log_errors on 
php_flag mysql.trace_mode on
    RewriteEngine On
        
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the output i should get in the webiste is :
index.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why url is not displayed on the website how can i solve this issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448938/why-url-is-not-displayed-on-the-website-how-can-i-solve-this-issue)

Comment: You need to edit your (previous) question to add the additional details requested in comments. From your question, it would seem you've done nothing to debug this?!

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_GET` global array gets only when you have GET request with key url.
If you want to get current url, you can use `$_SERVER` global array instead.

```
$current_url = sprintf(
    '%s://%s/%s',
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);
echo $current_url;
```

With this you can get current URL

Comment: "Because `$_GET` global array gets only when you have GET request with key URL." - which is the purpose of the `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess`.